# SVM - Scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I have a vector of scores (data) `X` with 3 variables (s1,s2,s3) like the `.shape` of X is `(n_sample,3)` , a vector class (target) `y` (2 class : 0 or 1).

I would like to build a weigthed score by combing them like `S=s1*w1+s2*w2+s3*w3`. For this I need to test different value for `w1`, `w2`, and `w3`, by using SVM (or SVR).

But i'm getting lost with all the parameters. Should I use `gamma` as a vector of weigth? And is it possible to have only one variable for `X`, I would like to have something la `(n_sample, 1)` but how to initialize it?

If you have suggestion by using something else than scikit-learn it's also fine for me.

Comment: I am a bit confused here. So you have 3 different score metrics, and you would like to combine them to produce a new score function? Or the scores is just the raw data, and you want to simply produce a combined feature?

Comment: Can you please describe more thoroughly the classification problem here? and what are these scores